Is anyone aware of a way to get power to internal accessories in a Dell Precision 5860 Tower?
I suspect I know the answer, but figure it is worth a shot anyways...
Is anyone aware of a way to get power to internal accessories in a Dell Precision 5860 Tower? It's a very nice setup if all you need to do is add drives - there are several permanently mounted SATA connectors. There are no standard power connectors or flexible SATA connectors.
Basically, I have a 5.25 bay device that needs to two power connections, and it doesn't have a standard SATA power / data connector that I could just plug into two of the drive connectors, it has just two SATA power connectors


A lot of dells are pretty much designed 'just' to support whatever its supposed to. I'd guess you have backplanes here plugged into something else. I'd wonder if your PSU is standard ATX and swappable, which would be the option here

What are the power requirements? Which Dell 5860 PS do you have - 750W or 1350W? Why can't you simply tap into one of the three 12VDC power leads from the PS, if all you need is 12VDC?

You could use a SATA extension that splits power and data (something like this SATA extension cord) to stick it into an unused SATA drive connector.
Amazon sells these, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00O077B24/. You can then use a SATA power splitter if you need more.
